# kafka consumer group max.poll.interval.ms not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set the consumer group property such that it can only **consume one message per minute**.

**consumer.properties**

```
group.id=test_group
max.poll.interval.ms=60000
session.timeout.ms=60000
max.poll.records=1
```

**Producer**

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:6667 --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT --topic cdc_poc
```

**Consumer**

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server d9lcwphd1e1:6667 --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT --consumer.config ~/kafka/consumer.properties --topic diyotta_cdc_poc
```

**Problem**
I don't see any wait for message consumption

Comment: so as soon as you publish the message you see it right?

Comment: yes, I need to consumer one message per minute not more than that

Comment: People usually want to consume ASAP. Add sleep() in your consumer. Assume that once you ask Kafka to give message from a topic then it will give it you right away if it can. Also, all available consumer configs are available at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs .

Comment: it seems there is no such configuration to control the polling period when running kafka consoleConsumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**max.poll.interval.ms** config is not for holding the consumer for delay, When using group management if consumer failed to poll in 60000 ms Zookeeper assume consumer is died and invokes the rebalancing.

Which mean after poll if consumer thread takes more than 60000 ms for subsequent poll then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalanced

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

**If kafka server have data then consumer will poll the records subsequently without any time delay**

Comment: then how do I achieve the dealy I want for consumer, is there any configuration I should consider?

Comment: I don't think so you can achevie this through properties, i hope there is no property for delay